# Get custom image attribute from category

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-attributes

How do I get a custom attribute from a category? I created an attribute in **category_form.xml** file and in the back-end I filled the field. But how do I get the field's value?

Thanks

Comment: where do you want to get it?